# Fastest way to select row with max value at primary key field

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have got a table:

```
CREATE TABLE spots(
    datetime TIMESTAMP,
    market VARCHAR(15),
    spot NUMERIC(10, 5),
    PRIMARY KEY (market, datetime)
);
```

I need to select row for `p_market` with maximum value of `datetime` filed, which is less or equal than `p_datetime`, so I have got two opts for this:

```
SELECT * FROM spots WHERE market = p_market AND datetime = (
    SELECT MAX(datetime) FROM spots WHERE market = p_market AND datetime <= p_datetime
);
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM spots WHERE market = p_market AND datetime <= p_datetime
ORDER BY datetime DESCENDING LIMIT 1;
```

So, the question is - which variant is better from the performance perspective.

Comment: Unless you have millions of rows or are doing that query thousands of times per app use case, it's unlikely to make a difference. Premature optimization, perhaps?

Comment: What RDBMS do you use?

Comment: Check the execution plan, but I would guess the second one will be faster. Another alternative is to use `distinct on`. Questions with this problem are tagged with `greatest-n-per-group` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+greatest-n-per-group

Answer (score 0):

Postgres supports [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-window.html), which should theoretically be calculated incrementally as rows are processed, so it should provide some performance boost over large data sets:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT *,
               RANK() OVER (ORDER BY datetime DESC) AS rk
        FROM   spots
        WHERE  market = p_market AND datetime <= p_datetime) t
FROM   spots 
WHERE  rk = 1
```